# How to request for getting down from a cab first?

Tags: synonyms, sentence, questions

How do I request fellow car pooling members so that I am dropped at my destination first?
Is 'Can I get down from the cab first?' correct?

Comment: Unclear.  Are you asking to get into the cab last, so that you can easily exit first, or are you asking that a multi-destination cab ride get to your destination first?

Comment: @HotLicks the second one...multi-destination cab ride..

Comment: Just make sure that from where you start, your destination is the closest.  There is a logical order based on shortest distance traveled to any multi-destination trip.   I would find it extremely annoying to ask that everyone in the car ride out to your house first and then have to circle back to drop everyone else off.    Now, if you made your friends aware that you had a strict deadline and then waited for them to offer to drop you off first- then great.   But don't say, "get *down* from a cab."

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information here to determine "how this should be asked." There is nothing ungrammatical about your example sentence . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical, in my experience (U.S.), usage is "drop off". Of your fellow passengers (from a multi-destination cab ride or carpool), as your comment indicates, you'd ask:

> May I be dropped off first?

This is meaning 5 from [oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drop)

> #### drop
>
> Set down or unload (a passenger or goods), especially on the way to somewhere else.
>
> ‘he dropped the load off at a dealer's’
> ‘his mum dropped him outside and drove off to work’